# Redirect url exact match with htaccess like case category on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need redirecting (301) page `https:/mysite.com/games/` to `https:/mysite.com/game-types/` but don't redirect pages like `https:/mysite.com/games/Diablo-2` etc. Only one specific page

I used options like this

`Redirect 301 /games/ https://mysite.loc/game-types/`

`Redirect 301 ^/games/$ ^/game-types/$`

`RewriteRule ^/games/$ ^/game-types/$ [R=301,L]`

`Redirect 301 https://mysite.loc/games/$ /game-types/$`

Also I tried use [redirect generator](https://www.301-redirect.online/htaccess-rewrite-generator)

```
# Code generated by www.301-redirect.online
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^games/$ https://mysite.loc/game-types/? [R=301,L]
```

But all that's variants don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/games/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^games/ /game-types/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/games [NC]
RewriteRule ^games /game-types/ [NC]
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work `https:/mysite.com/games/Diablo-2/` => `http://mysite.loc/game-types/Diablo-2/`

Comment: You are incorrect, it works. The reason you cant see it working is because you are typing an incorrect URL prefix, there is no such thing as https:/ you should be typing https://

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made mistake in comment. I have the same 'http' protocol in both cases. But it still don't work.

Comment: It 100% works, I have verified that it works in the below link. You obviously have some other issue. https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: This is my .htaccess for wordpress  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/games/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^games/ /game-types/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/games [NC]
RewriteRule ^games /game-types/ [NC]

</IfModule> ` and it's not work right

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled ?

Comment: I got the same result on a local server Openserver Apache2.4-PHP7.0-7.1 Could this problem be due to the fact that the file belongs to a custom taxonomy ? (`register_taxonomy`)

Comment: do you have mod_rewrite enabled ?